# PyQt5 Serial port threadevent

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to send event `emit()` message every time I got packet of data for serial port. 
Serial port is working trough threading system and it collecting data.
My problem is that I'cant trigger event to call my function from serial thread.

Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import serial as pyserial
import threading

class Com_port(QThread):
    rcv_data_event = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(Com_port, self).__init__()
        self.serial = pyserial.Serial()
        self.serial.port=kwds.pop('port')
        self.serial.baudrate=kwds.pop('baudrate')
        self.serial.bytesize=pyserial.EIGHTBITS
        self.serial.parity=pyserial.PARITY_NONE
        self.serial.stopbits=pyserial.STOPBITS_ONE
        self.serial.timeout=None
        self.serial.xonxoff=0
        self.serial.rtscts=0
        self.serial.interCharTimeout=None
        self.thread = None
        self.alive = threading.Event()
        self.buffer = kwds.pop('buffer')
        self.rcv_data_event.connect(self.rcvData_signal)
        self.rcv_data_event.emit()  # This is working
        pass

        try:
            self.serial.open()
        except pyserial.SerialException:
            print ('Failed to connect com port !')

    def StartThread(self):
        """Start the receiver thread"""
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.ComPortThread)
        self.thread.setDaemon(1)
        self.alive.set()
        self.thread.start()

    def StopThread(self):
        """Stop the receiver thread, wait util it's finished."""
        if self.thread is not None:
            self.alive.clear()          # clear alive event for thread
            self.thread.join()          # wait until thread has finished
            self.thread = None

    def CloseSerialPort(self):
        self.serial.flushInput()
        self.serial.flushOutput()
        self.serial.close()

    def ComPortThread(self):
        while self.alive.isSet():               #loop while alive event is true
            try:
                if self.serial.inWaiting() and self.serial.is_open:
                    self.bajt = self.serial.read(self.buffer)
                    print(self.bajt, sep='', end='\n')
                    self.rcv_data_event.emit()  #This is not working :(
                    pass
            except:
                # PRIKAZATI GRESKU !!!!
                print ('Failed to connect com port !')
                self.StopThread()
                ok = False

    def rcvData_signal(self):
        print("Start serial port data event")
        print("Not reveiving any data  from serial thread :( :( :( WHY")
```

---

`rcvData_Signal` is called only once, from **def __init__** function, but from `ComPortThread()` never.

I have previewed many questions, but couldn't find solution for **pyQT5**.

:(

Comment: It is not good to combine QThread with threading, I think that is one of the reasons, debug a program with threads is hard, imagine the mixture you have, I recommend or use Qthread or use threading, also another recommendation would be to use QSerialPort, it's class is Friendly with the GUI in addition to having the signal you want already implemented.

Comment: Is possible to use QSerial port from PyQt5 ?

Comment: Yes, what is your OS?

Comment: execute this: `from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import *`

Comment: Why you use 2 threads, the first is the QThread and the second the threading?

Comment: Why am I using 2 threads? 

Have no idea.  I'm complete beginer in python and PyQt5. This code is assembled from many examples collected arround.  :(

Comment: Try to understand the code you create but you will get another monstrosity similar to the one you show.

Comment: I had wrote new program using  PyQt5.QtSerialPort and testing it.

Thank you all for answers !